# Error "Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm" while "npx create-react-app example_app"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When I was trying to create a new react app using `npx create-react-app example_app`, I get this error

> [Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous
>   versions of npm which has since been addressed sudo chown -R 0:0
>   "/root/.npm"]

I even tried to re-install `create-react-app` again using `npm i create-react-app`, it is giving the same kind of
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9QJA.png).

I assume after searching about it that it is due to some permissions issue. My current user doesn't have permission to `/home/shubham/.npm` where `shubham` is my username, but I am not so sure about this.

I have tried to solve this error using `chown` command as

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> /home/shubham/.npm"
```

where `<username>` is `Shubham` and `<groupame>` is `1000`, but it is still not working.

Request people to help me out.
If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: i have same error here. hope somebody have solution!

Comment: i am also having this same issue

Comment: Had the same thing inside Docker. Merely restarting the container fixed it.

Answer (score 90):

This worked for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried with the given command, still getting same error

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! Here is the reason for those interested. https://coder-coder.com/npm-clear-cache/#:~:text=Run%3A%20%E2%80%9Cnpm%20cache%20clean%20%E2%80%93,npm%20cache%20on%20your%20computer.

Answer (score 14):

In case you're facing this issue and don't have root access to fix the permissions for the current NPM cache folder, one way to go around the error is by defining a different cache dir.

First, create a new directory for the cache. Then, set the `npm_config_cache` environment variable:

**In Linux**

```
export npm_config_cache=/path/to/cache
```

**In Windows**

```
set npm_config_cache=/path/to/cache
```

Comment: Where is this set to by default, and why does it work?

Comment: This works for our case.
In the Dockerfile, we needed to add `ENV npm_config_cache /home/node/app/.npm`. This appears to be accessible to write for the Docker containers.

Answer (score 10):

This is what helped me after going through the above answers. I hope it helps someone else too. After re-reading the npm error prompt, I adjusted the provided command to include the .npm path given in the error message. Below is a copy of my original error messages.

> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! syscall access
>
> npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/**.npm-global**/lib/node_modules
>
> npm ERR! errno -13
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
>
> npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
>
> npm ERR! sudo chown -R 900:900 "/home/vagrant/.npm"
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!  /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-07-09T16_43_35_046Z-debug.log
>
> [ExecStack]  Exit code 243  Time 01:03
>
> [error]  Executing target-hook frontend-reqs failed.
>
> [error]  Command `source:build:frontend-reqs`  exited with code 1.

Instead of using **sudo chown -R 900:900 "/home/vagrant/.npm"**, I used **sudo chown -R 900:900 "/home/vagrant/.npm-global"**. After that, I was able to use the previous command that caused the error with no issues.

Answer (score 7):

Try `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/shubham/.npm"`

Comment: Tried with this command, still getting the same error.

[
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm which has since been addressed. To permanently fix this problem, please run:
sudo chown -R 0:0 "/home/shubham/.npm"
]

Comment: Did you also clean npm cache?

Comment: I have cleaned npm cache using "npm cache clean --force" as "npm cache clean" was giving error "As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals".

But now when i tried to run "npx create-react-app example_app”, it gets stucked while creating the app in middle of progress bar.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried with the given command, still getting same error

Comment: this one worked out for me

Answer (score 4):

If you are using CI and share the CI slave with other teams, maybe not possible to `sudo chown -R {group}:{user} "~/.npm"` (i.e.: using Github Enterprise with Github Actions on shared runners

I add

```
# use local cache to work-around 'npm ERR! path ~/.npm/_locks/staging-xxx.lock' in GHA
cache=./npm-cache
```

into my .npmrc in the repo to solve the issue by using local npm cache dir

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this while running `npx @11ty/eleventy` as root:

```
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"
```

No,  `/root/.npm` is *supposed* to be owned by root.  It's not at all due to a bug in a previous version of npm.  And yes, the root user has permission to read and write that directory.  So this is a bug in the *current* version of npm that prevents building the project as root.

Of course following the nonsensical instructions to change the root homedir's ownership does not work.

In my case, I was running it as root as part of a build script that needs root for an `rsync` to complete:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
# mybuildscript

npx @11ty/eleventy
rsync _site/ /srv/www/ # This needs to be run as root
```

So my workaround was to run that single line as an unprivileged user using `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
# mybuildscript

sudo -u ki9 npx @11ty/eleventy
rsync _site/ /srv/www/ # This needs to be run as root
```

I am using npm version `7.5.2`.  Hopefully this will be addressed in a future version of npm.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and several others while trying to update my npm packages. I will be honest I do not have enough knowledge of package handlers or why this fixed my situation, but I believe my version of npm and npx were causing the issues. I had errors immediately trying to install npx, node and create-react-app with my old and out of date version of npm.

I could not run `npm install npx -g` without `--force`. Once I did that I also ran `npm install npm -g --force`. After this I could already tell things were different.

After npm and npx were completely overwritten, I ran `npm install node -g` and `npm install create-react-app -g` without any weird problems. I created a new react app and started it error free.

(I also ran the cache command before all of this. `sudo npm cache clean --force` which I am unsure if it helped).

Answer (score 3):

I had to do both the root folder and the `root/.npm`

```
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 "/root"
sudo chown -R 1001:1001 "/root/.npm"
```

Comment: This will change ownership of the root user's homedir and could result in unintended consequences.

Comment: Bro, please don't do this

Answer (score 3):

I fixed mine by running:

```
  sudo npm cache clean --force
```

followed by removing the root owned files.
first, to view the file owners and group:

```
cd /Users/username/
ls -la
```

You have to check the owner of .npm, changed to non-root user:

```
 sudo chown -R username:group "/Users/username/.npm"
```

or for global .npm-global

```
 sudo chown -R username:group "/Users/username/.npm-global"
```

replace keyword: username/group accordingly

Comment: Finally fixed this bug after several days, this was the only working answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also tried all of the above steps on my MAC Catalina, but didn't resolve my issue. These steps resolved my problem:

```
npm update
npx --ignore-existing create-react-app my-app
```

Thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8085#issuecomment-563200289)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:
`sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "~/.npm"`

Answer (score 0):

Neither force-cleaning the cache nor using `chown` worked for me, but deleting the folder did work and fixed the issue.

My error was:

```
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/aw/.npm"
```

The fix was to permanently erase the `.npm` folder in question, which I did using `rm -rf`:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Users/aw/.npm
```

(Mandatory warning: this is a dangerous command if you typo it.)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and the problem with mine was that I was running an older version of npm. After updating npm and removing the .npmrc file, it worked just fine.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
rm .npmrc
```

**Be careful before deleting the .npmrc file, take a backup as it will reset your npm configuration.**

Comment: There is no reason to remove your npmrc file, what you have done here is just update the npm version, not resolve the npm cache issue.

Comment: npm install -g npm@latest           ...         worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am working in laravel with webpack not vite.
And have this problem too.
Also i am working with docker and i founded solution to run watch without cache.

In bash i create an alias

```
alias dc-watch-no-cache="docker-compose exec node npm run --cache /var/cache/ watch"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me :**

sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/Hichem/.npm-global

npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did the simple thing by adding sudo and typing the password to the command, in you case, `sudo npm i create-react-app`, this solved the issue, especially with company computers

Answer (score 0):

update your npx package to the latest version use npx update in the terminal it worked for me

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score -1):

**It work for me now!**

What I did? (**I'm not saying it's the best way to fix this but i'ts working for me. I'm still looking for the best explications for this issue**)

```
  sudo rm -Rf /home/[YOUR_USER_NAME]/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/
```

and run your command again.

My explication is that it seems like something is corrupted in the node_modules's folder.
As it's not risky to delete it I did it and it works now.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I tried with the given command, still getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

It helped me: 
Remove and install npm again

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, just try commenting through it, I think he already tried that

Comment: Right,I have already tried the same. Still not able to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo npx create-react-app example_app` or in my case `sudo npm install @vue/cli`

I tried everything else here, but in the end realised that it might just be the command that I was running was not able to escalate the correct permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Find error in your log file:

> ```
> verbose Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/xxx/.tnpm_tmp/npm-52731-e91f6671'
> ```

Use that error in your condition.

```
sudo chown -R 502:20 "/Users/XXX/.tnpm_tmp"
```

Answer (score -2):

I solve the problem with the following commands

1. Install dependence > `npm install create-react-app`
2. run > `create-react-app project_name`

happy hack!!

Answer (score -6):

Try to create your react app using yarn package manager.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).