# Error "Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, create-react-app, npm-install

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 Stable version. I installed latest stable version of Node.js (v12.16.1) and npm (v6.13.4).

When i was trying to install "create-react-app" using "npm i create-react-app", I am getting error.
[image]

**`Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm which has since been addressed`**

I have tried **`sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/shubham/.npm"`**, but still getting same error.

Request people to help me out.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in previous versions of npm" while "npx create-react-app example\_app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437833/error-your-cache-folder-contains-root-owned-files-due-to-a-bug-in-previous-ver)

Comment: The link above has no accepted answers

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and saw this:[image]

One of my issues was that `/npm` did not exist. I created `/npm` and  and then ran the suggested command `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/npm"` and it seemed to work. I also ran into the same issue with ~/.npm - I believe the difference is that one is global and the other is local.